# Javascript - Reference to param of function itself

Tags: javascript, list, function, parameters

I have function for search value of column in list, and it looks like this

```
function search(list, column, key) {
    var result = []
    for (var i in list) {
        if (list[i].column.includes(key)) { //I think it will looking any field named column instead takes the one from parameter
            result.push(list[i])
        }
    }
    return result
}
```

The problem is how do i change which column i use dynamically based on parameter of the function? Thanks.

Comment: what do you mean by column as reference ? a example snippet maybe?

Comment: I mean i want to change which column i use dynamically based on parameter of the function